# Can an anonymous function in MATLAB have more than one line?

Tags: matlab

I've seen anonymous functions like:

```
@(eta) 30*eta^2;
```

but they mostly are one liners. Is it possible to have them have more than one line like:

```
@(eta) (x =eta^2;
y=eta^3;
return x+y;
)
```

where one has more lines and variables defined in the anonymous function but let it remain as an anonymous function?

Comment: @horchler THanks! it seems it could be the same!

Comment: why is this receiving down votes? If its a duplicate, should I just erase it? I don't understand whats going on.